# Полные и неполные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Как определить полное предложение или нет, если оно содержит тире между подлежщим и сказуемым? Допустим:
Учение - семена знаний, а знания - семена счастья.
Я считаю что оба простых предложения неполные, верно?
Или вот:
Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи - никель и хром.
Первое полное, а второе нет. Да?
Всем благодарна за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Учение - семена знаний, а знания - семена счастья.-оба простых предл. полные, здесь не пропущен ни один член предложения, который надо было бы восстановить из контекста. Предложения с нулевой связкой в составном именном сказуемом неполными не считаются. Сказуемое там есть.

Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи - никель и хром. -простое полное предложение с обособленными однородными определениями, стоят в конце предложения, поэтому поставлено тире (как приложения).
 О неполных предложениях почитайте здесь:
http://www.lingvotech.com/nepolnie_predlozheniya

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи - никель и хром.
Подлежащее - родичи, никель, хром; сказуемое - поднялись?

Comment: Если я правильно поняла, то в предложении "Грушницкий - юнкер" есть нулевая связка, и поэтому оно считается полным.
А что насчет таких предложений как: "У самой горы виднелась крестьянская хижина, а напротив - мельница на берегу ручья". Первое предложение полное, а второе неполное, ведь в нем нет нулевой связки, а просто пропущено сказуемое, которое восстанавливается из первой части предложения.
Если я не права, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Я неверно выразилась: никель и хром - однородные  подлежащие,родичи -приложение. Тире, потому что распространённое приложение разъясняется подлежащими. Иногда сложно различить, где приложение, где определяемое слово, я не вдумалась, не думала, что Вам это важно.
"Грушницкий - юнкер" - полное.У самой горы виднелась крестьянская хижина, а напротив - мельница на берегу ручья". -верно, второе неполное с пропуском сказуемого"виднелась".

Comment: Да, очень важно! Плохо понимаю эту тему, поэтому пытаюсь хорошенько в ней разобраться. Хотела бы снова Вас поблагодарить! Хорошо, что есть еще отзывчивые люди!

Comment: Рада помочь. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

"Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи - никель и хром". А разве подлежащее, будучи главным членом предложения, может обособляться?

Comment: Да уж...Обособлено-то приложение, конечно. Выходит,никель и хром - приложения, они объясняют, кто именно является родичами. А родичи - подлежащее.
http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm